# Binding SignalR, User ID Provider for SignalR 2.0 and knockout.js views together for realtime data updates

Tags: c#, knockout.js, signalr, signalr-hub

Security matters aside, since it's a whole another topic.

Say, I have the following client side implementation which leverages the `knockout.js` `observables` and `computed observables`.

```
// Define the global 'app' object
var app = {
    data: {
        userProfile: ko.observable()
    }
}

// Define the viewModel and subscribe to the app.data.userProfile() changes
var viewModel = {
    profile: ko.computed(function(){ return app.data.userProfile(); });
}

// Establish the hub connection
var profileHub = $.connection.profileHub;

// Define the client method
profileHub.client.userProfile = function (profile) {
    app.data.userProfile(profile);
};

// Start the hub
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Bind the viewModel to the view
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

After this, provided that I use the User ID Provider for SignalR 2.0, I should be able to call the following from my hub.

```
public class ProfileHub : Hub
{
    public void UserProfile(UserProfile profile)
    {
        Clients.User(profile.userId).send(profile);
    }
}
```

Which effectively would bind the updated information to the user's view.

---

Somewhere along the way, user submits their updated profile to the server (details omitted) and we end up storing it to the backend

---

Let's say I have the following C# code to persist information to the backend in my BLL.

```
MyDal.Instance.UpdateProfile(profile, DalSuccessAction, DalFailureAction);
```

And the `DalSuccessAction` as follows:

```
protected void DalSuccessAction(IEntity entity){

    // Handle caching through the interface
    entity.ToCache();

    if (entity is UserProfile) {
        // Should I call the Hub directly here or is there a better way (design-wise) going about it?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to apply your bindings to *something*, namely your VM; Knockout can't guess what it is

```
// Start the hub
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Bind the viewModel to the view
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I missed that in the code. However, that's not what I'm asking here. The code herein is not in any system, thus I don't have any bug to fix. I'm trying to figure out the best way of interacting between my BLL and Hubs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you keep your layers logic separated. Which means MVC App should be the one dealing with the client calls not BLL or DAL.

You can achieve this by returning the result of UpdateProfile method to your controller/Hub/etc.. (and maybe converting it to a ViewModel object if needed).